# Duality (conjugate) function for $f \in L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

For $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, can I find the $f^*\in (L^\infty(\mathbb{R}))^*$ such that 
$$\|f^*\|_* = 1 \text{ and } \langle f^*, f \rangle = \|f\|_\infty.$$

I know that $(L^\infty(\mathbb{R}))^*$ is the space of bounded finitely additive measures that are absolute continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. So I need to find a $\lambda\in ba(\mathbb{R})$ such that 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f d\lambda = \|f\|_\infty \quad \text{ and } \quad \|\lambda\|_{var}(\mathbb{R}) = 1.$$

Is this a well known result, specific for $L^\infty$?

I stared looking at simple functions, for 
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \chi_{A_i}$$
As Martini said, we could define our 
$$\lambda(A) = \frac{1}{\mu(A_i)} \lambda (A\cap A_I)$$
for $i$ such that $|c_i|$ is maximal.

But then I am stuck at the next step again when generalizing this to continuous functions because when approximate a $L^\infty$ function with simple functions, the measure of the maximal set $A_i$ might go to zero.

Comment: Note that $\delta_x$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, but you can take $\lambda(A) = \frac 1{\mathrm{Leb}(A_i)}\cdot \mathrm{Leb}(A \cap A_i)$, for $i$ such that $|c_i|$ is maximal, which has density $\frac 1{\mathrm{Leb}(A_i)}\cdot \chi_{A_i}$

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! I ran into another problem when doing the approximation argument. There is no way of controlling $\mu(A_i)$ and it might go to zero..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**. This follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Indeed, for each non-zero element $x$ in a Banach space $X$, there is a norm-one functional $f\in X^*$ such that $\langle f,x\rangle = \|x\|$. To see this, consider the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x$. Let $\langle f,cx\rangle = c\|x\|$ ($c$ is a scalar). Then $f$ is a norm-one functional that can be extended to the whole of $X$ in a norm-preserving way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I meant the result specific for $L^\infty$, like the conjugate function for $L^p$. For example $f\in L^p$ we can define the conjugate function to be $$\|f\|_p^{1-p}|f|^{p-2} f \in L^q.$$

Comment: The elements of $L_\infty^*$ are measures rather than functions. Can you clarify your question, please?